# SFC wants to replace dwmapi.dll to a blackscreen

Tags: windows-7, dll, black-screen-of-death

All my game cds have been tossed out and turned into ISO's.  I installed the game Cities Skyline i have via WinCDEmu, then when comodo firewall started flagging things for my permission.  I allowed it to make an update to `dwmapi.dll`, then immediately suspected it was maybe a pirated iso copy and not my original, since it was an uncommon dll file that it targeted, at least i thought.  I guess its one of the main windows managers.

I got cold feet, and immediately tried to undo this, `SFC` found no problems on it directly after the install, but I couldn't get an MD5 match anywhere on the newly edited file version, using all other known instanced of this file i could find, including internet md5 resources.  So i took it upon my self to replace it, what a PIA this has become.

What i did was i pulled `dwmapi.dll` from my DVD source doing a manual copy using 7zip, and THEN i received the black screen on boot. i.e. NO window.

Then i pulled out the repair disks, after i realized `SafeMode` was also blackscreen.  Cmd prompt SFC was complaining that it had a pending operation and  sysrestore wouldn't work, i had the wrong repair disc it said for all my rescue/install dvd's I have.

I then manually replaced the file with a backup copy i made before i started the whole operation (of the suspected hacked one) painstakingly after having to fall-wayyy-back to `Hiram's mini-xp`.
Ok, all said and done, my system boots fine, loads fine, looks fine, but now i have a different version of the `dll` file, and SFC says its corrupted.  I tried to replace it with SFC caused a bad loop of the same issue, reboot to black...

So, now at this moment, i have a seeming normal working system, **However** SFC says is corrupt.

**Q** How can i find the right version, or what can i do?

Edit: I do still have the original edited dll file here. Here are the file Specs (this is the suspected trojanized version)
**dwmapi.dll version 6.1.7600.16385 80.5kb** MD5 `da1b7075`

**Q** Is this a good version?  I can just put it back and be done with this if so.  Or, is there a location i can upload it to have it inspected properly?

Also in my notes, i have this hash `52213d271f6804aaa44`, i think its the one that i replaced with thats causing the black screen, cant be certain, however its one i was having a problem with, and wasnt able to find that as a valid hash for my win version **Win-7 Ult x64**

Edit: so today, i got an appcrash from Dwm, not sure if this is related.  Still waiting to see how i can get the correct DWM back, that SFC is happy with.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Dwm.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.7600.16385
  Application Timestamp:    4a5bc541
  Fault Module Name:    atiuxp64.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.14.1.6463
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55c0180e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000018405
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 40c9
  Additional Information 2: 40c96b40a2f01759eb81da4cd327fcd4
  Additional Information 3: cb4a
  Additional Information 4: cb4a71b6596c17a6581581aded8f3f1d
```

Comment: Sounds like your anti-virus is detected a false postive.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How so, it didn't say it was virus laden, it just asked me if i wanted to allow changes, but why do you say its positive if the md5 matched no known instance of valid dll file?  What would be really helpful is to know what the md5 "should" be.  Mind you, SFC is breaking my windows, which is not supposed to be the case, so something is still very wrong.

Comment: You pulled an outdated copy of the file from your DVD I guarantee you that file has been patched in the past. You understand what I mean by "false positive" right? It means the file is NOT a virus.

Comment: Yes thankyou, so you think file is outdated that i pulled from dvd, and a what, windows update has updated it?  What might the game wanted to do to it though?  and what course of action should i take if SFC wants to delete it and blackscreen me, its a no win situation as it stands, i dont know how to repair properly.

Comment: still struggling with this, anyone?